# change cursor on web page

Tags: css, firefox, mouse-cursor

I am trying to change cursor with .gif image. It will be shown on whole page not only one link. I made it like

```css
body {
    cursor:url(Butterfly.gif);
}
```

it does not work. I have also `.cur` file. It works on IE but not on Firefox.

Comment: I am usually not a fan of people changing my mouse to some funny image.  Perhaps I would enjoy a butterfly "floating" around my screen.

Comment: but site for kids.It should be funny for them)

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/cursor and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/cursor for compatibility infos. You'll need to post more infos such as a link to a (non-)working page for more help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add a fallback, e.g.

```
body {
  cursor: url(Butterfly.gif), url(Butterfly.ani), auto;
  /*                                            ^^^^^^ 
                                                compulsory, according to CSS 2.1
   */
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property for detail.

Comment: @Meko: It's because IE doesn't support `.gif`. It is explained in the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist, you have to use the `.cur` file for the sake of Internet Explorer.

> Internet Explorer up to and including
>   version 8 only support URI values of
>   type .CUR and .ANI. (The other listed
>   browsers list have support for .CUR,
>   .PNG, .GIF and .JPG but not .ANI .)
>   Note also that the Windows operating
>   system requires the image to be 32 x
>   32 pixels or smaller although the
>   specifications do allow for larger
>   sizes than this.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/cursor

Although I'd say don't use it at all.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the absolute path (`http://www.example.com/images/Butterfly.gif`) to be sure that it works at all, instead of the relative path (`Butterfly.gif`).

Comment: I used also absolute path but .gif not working .I searched tutorials and all says that .gif works.

Comment: @Meko: ah well, it was worth a try. You're probably looking at @KennyTM's answer being the most likely to help, then.